# How to use an LC stage as a voltage amplifier?

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor, passive-networks, voltage-amplification

**What I have done**

From my simulation [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0AsYBMBmTD0E48B2dANjwA50xMQFJbb6EBTAWjDACgA3EFc%20mDzo%20AkJnIoo4cAjwQk9JdAScA7qMHCQhSeG2R1OvUJG6p6dFMMbzIS1MKYS9q1CN2HIcphFfDAMY6zq6OITgiyvCQEDAkcHgIkoSE-FYkhLGwMZwANt6%20oQUiEdIwcBCsMCh4JJiZcmTkCJgohIoe4bjGUqU2xeLddn0eeqXDev0TUnIlk5wATprierMr1oycQA), I have tried using a parallel LC stage as a voltage amplifier at resonance.

$$f = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt[]{LC}}$$
$$L = 0.001$$
$$C = 10 \cdot 10^{-6}$$
$$\therefore f \approx 1591$$

I have tried it above and below this frequency with no luck.

---

**My question**

How do you build a voltage amplifier with an LC stage like the one I have?

This is my circuit:

[image]

Comment: *which* kind of LC stage do you have? *How* did you try? At what frequencies precisely did you try? Plus: L and C have units, and they matter :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have added an image of my circuit into my question. I have tried it at 60 Hz, 1591 Hz, and 10 kHz, and even 1 MHz.

Comment: ah, how could that lead to a voltage increase? your oscillating circuit is in parallel with a voltage source!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am still new to LC circuits, apologies for that. I was just experimenting with the simulation.

Comment: I thought you've been building oscillators for months now? Certainly, you can analyze this circuit on paper by now! I'd recommend sitting down and trying, you'll surprise yourself how far you'll get with the bit of complex linear network analysis you've acquired. If you meet an obstacle on the way - ask! That kind of question will take you further than saying "I've simulated a random thing, it doesn't do, what's wrong": People will understandably confused by where that approach comes from, as writing this down would make the problem pretty tangible, pretty quick.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you recommend any texts or resources that can help me with oscillator analysis?

Comment: At this level: no! You don't need any specific oscillator books, you just need to apply complex linear network analysis on your rather straightforward linear networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How do you build a voltage amplifier with an LC stage like the one  I have?*

Try re-wiring your filter circuit like this: -

[image]

Your current circuit will not produce amplification. Note that the resistance needs to be 1 Ω to get 20 dB amplification with L and C as you currently have them.

[web calculator here](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html).

Or maybe this circuit might be more appealing: -

[image]

Comment: It is possible to switch the inductor and the cap to get the same effect? What would happen?

Comment: @shocked [try this](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20HPF/RCL%20HPF.html)